# How to create nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, format, nested, concatenation

I've been looking all over stackoverflow for something to help me implement an AreaChart. The problem is that I have something like this.

```
var items = new Array();
if ($(result).find('dato').length > 0 ) {
  items = ["Date", "Kg Emitted", "Kg Reduced"];
  $(result).find('dato').each(
    function (i) {
      var item = new Array();
      var date = $(this).find("fecha").first().text();
      var kge = parseInt($(this).find("emitido").first().text());
      var kgr = parseInt($(this).find("reducido").first().text());
      item = [date,kge,kgr];
      items.push.apply(items, item)
    }
  );
};
```

The problem is that I need it in a format like:

`items = ["Date","Kg Emitted", "Kg reduced"], [2013-01-01, 3, 4], [2013-01-02, 1, 3], etc`

I would appreciate any help on how to format this nested array, because so far I've tried `items.push.apply(items, item)`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention. This each method is getting an ajax with an xml formated var that contains fecha, emitido and reducido, which is date, Kg Emitted and Kg reduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everybody gave you the right answer here, 
i want to add just a little fix, the first value in your array is incorrect and is actually 3 rows.

See the difference [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8754/)

you need to add another `[..]` .

Comment: I did everything you guys told me, But the graph wasn't working, so I put an alert(items[0] + " " + items[1]+ " " + items[2]); And what I got was Date,Kg Emitted,Kg Reduced Date,Kg Emitted,Kg Reduced,,04-06-2013,1,0,,05-06-2013,8,0,,06-06-2013,1,0,,07-06-2013,21,0,,08-06-2013,1,0,,09-06-2013,20,0,,10-06-2013,1,0 04-06-2013,1,0 ....why is repeating data?

Comment: I just realized that I had items.push(items,item); I'm testing to see if that was it

Answer (score 1):

Just change `items.push.apply(items, item)` to `items.push(item)`.

When you use apply like that you are effectively doing the same thing as [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization of `items` isn't setting it up as a nested array.  Element 0 is "Date", 1 is "Kg Emitted" and 2 is "Kg Reduced".

You want to start it with

```
items = [["Date", "Kg Emitted", "Kg Reduced"]];
```

This will instead make Element 0 of the array be ["Date", "Kg Emitted", "Kg Reduced"], which is what you say you want.

Then, as others have already said, change `items.push.apply(items, item)` to

```
items.push(item);
```